# Airflow: Have a dag know when the next scheduled time is

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG scheduled to run 12 times per day, but sometimes is manually triggered more than that. I would like for the DAG to know if it is a scheduled trigger, if so if it is the last scheduled run of the day then it should do something else.

How can I determine within a dag if it is the last scheduled one of the day (for that specific dag id)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing out of the box in Airflow to tell you if it's "the last scheduled interval of the day". However, you can implement such behavior yourself.

Say your cron schedule is `"0 */2 * * *"`. The last schedule of the day would be from `22:00:00` to `00:00:00` (the next day). We can use this information to give different behaviour, for example:

```py
import datetime

import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowSkipException
from airflow.models import DagRun
from airflow.utils.types import DagRunType


@dag(schedule="0 */2 * * *", start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 20))
def so_76559726():
    @task
    def check_last_run_of_day(
        data_interval_start: pendulum.DateTime = None,
        data_interval_end: pendulum.DateTime = None,
        dag_run: DagRun = None,
    ):
        print(f"The interval start is {data_interval_start}")
        print(f"The interval end is {data_interval_end}")
        print(f"The run type is {dag_run.run_type}")

        if (data_interval_end.date() - data_interval_start.date()).days == 1 and dag_run.run_type == DagRunType.SCHEDULED:
            raise AirflowSkipException("Skip the last interval of the day.")

    check_last_run_of_day()


so_76559726()
```

In this DAG, the condition `if (data_interval_end.date() - data_interval_start.date()).days == 1` is `True` when the end date of the interval is in the following day, and the condition `dag_run.run_type == DagRunType.SCHEDULED` is only valid on scheduled DAG runs.

To make this visually easily identifiable, I raised an AirflowSkipException in the task, but you can implement whatever behavior you wish in this situation:

[image]